# What is faster? jQuery css(), jQuery addclass() or just css

Tags: jquery, css

Ok in this case I ONLY focus on speed.

What is faster?

1. `$('#header').css({'background':'#ff0000','width':'100px','height':'100px'});`
2. `$('#header').addClass('header');`
3. Just use #header in css

I can't get the answer by using FireBug.

Comment: The third, obviously !

Comment: @Bondye Because it's not executing **any** JavaScript.

Comment: *What is the faster : put a rock on the table, or give this rock to a third person, and ask him to put it on the table ?* You're using a useless middleman in both first and second points.

Comment: Also, `addClass()` will be faster than `css()`, [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-css-vs-addclass)

Comment: @samsamX When I load the .css file it took some ms. So extually i ask for the rock and then put it on the table.

Comment: Mmmh right, I didn't thought that way. But you'll always need a CSS file (well, in 99.99999% of cases), then it'll be faster to use this already-loaded-css than JS.

Comment: i you want to  less than 1-4 atributes set css, if more try with addClass, it will be more flexible, but css is the only 'right' way to do this :)

Comment: Inline styles are probably faster then an external stylesheet, but what you loose in regards to seperation of code is'nt worth it for most people. Using javascript to set styles will always be slower, no matter how you do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use Embedded CSS, that is `#header` in css on our page. If you try to apply CSS using JavaScript, your page may not display correctly if JavaScript on browser is disabled. You may use external CSS file, embedded css on head and the inline CSS.

Always give priority to pure HTML and CSS. Trust me, its faster.